# google cloud endpoints /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/myapi/v1/rpc takes half a minute to load

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

Very often, `https://myversion-dot-my-module-dot-my-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/archivedash/v1/rpc?fields=methods%2F*%2Fid&pp=0` can take half a minute to load.

[image]

This is killing the load time of my app.

Searching the logs under that version & module with `path:/_ah/api.*` gives not results - so I can't see what's slowing it down. Also the warmup requests usually take less than a few seconds so it's not that?

Comment: it's running fairly quickly now - just irks me slightly that I'm not sure what was taking the link so long earlier. (and this was slow last week too). Perhaps I had exceeded some kind of quota.

Comment: today again it took 10 seconds to load. - after refreshing it is usually fast again.

Comment: Generally in the mornings It takes around about 10 seconds the first few times I hit it. Perhaps If I had consistent, high QPS then it would perform better - will try do some more scientific performance measurements. - however I'm not sure that my api will ever have consistent high QPS. I guess I need to make sure it's not something else in my app causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this related issue here https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10017